# Switching between 2 table objects in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pretty new to react and I'm having trouble switching between these 2 tables. I looked at the documentation for inline conditional statements and this was all I got. I want it to switch between the tables after clicking the button.

```
const customer_table = (
  <Table striped bordered hover>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Org Name</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>More Info</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {customers.map(customer => 
    <tr>
      <td id="customer_id">{String(customer.customer_id).padStart(4, '0')}</td>
      <td id="name">{customer.org_name}</td>
      <td id="email">{customer.cus_status}</td>
      <td><Link to={{
        pathname: `/profile/${customer.customer_id}`,
        query: { customer_id: `${customer.customer_id}`}
      }} className="btn btn-primary">Profile</Link></td>
    </tr>
  )}
  </tbody>
</Table>
)
return (
    <td>
      <div className="toggleCustomers">
        <button onClick={toggleDeavtivated} >Show Deactivated Customers</button>
      </div>
    <ul>
    {
      show_deactivated ? `${deactivatedCustomer_table}` 
      : `${customer_table}`
    }
   </ul>
   </td>
);
```

Comment: what is the `deactivatedCustomer_table` and `customer_table` type?

Comment: This tables are in render function. So they has to contain react element, if you have some other data in this table then you have to map it by using map function of array and return array of react elements.

Comment: the tables are react bootstrap tables

Comment: Can you update the question to include the table component(s)?

Answer (score 0):

To do that you need to use state, you can read about this from this [url](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

By using state you can update rendering by track any change from button, for example for your case:

```
    const [firstTable, setFirstTable] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {firstTable}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setFirstTable(!firstTable)}>
        Click me
      </button>
         { firstTable ? ${deactivatedCustomer_table}` 
         : `${customer_table}`
       }
    </div>
  );
```